# Create Third Array based on information of two arrays only with numpy functions (without iterating / looping)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a complex function, which takes two arguments x and y and returns an integer value i. The information i is saved in a numpy array FF with the shape (200,200). The Element values i in FF are between 0 and 39999 and are not assigned twice within the whole array.
The Array FF is precalculated and exists when Array SF is created. (see below) *Additional info: the complex function calculates the position of a bit in a NxN matrix of a qrcode, which can be precalculated for every qrcode version and ecc*

The second function, which creates a one dimensional array SF of boolean values with the function SF[i], so it has the shape (40000,).
The array is created with

```
SF = numpy.fromfunction((lambda i: ((data[i >> 3] >> 7 - (i & 7)) & 1 != 0)), (40000,))
```

, where data[] is an array with bytes. *(Additional info: The function evaluates every bit of every byte as true or false.)*

Important to know: *FF[x][y] = i* describes the position of the desired information in the SF array.

**My problem**

Is there an integrated FAST numpy function (or a consecutive application of NUMPY functions), which can (WITHOUT slow python iterating, enumeration or for loops) combine the two arrays FF and SF, so that the target array TARGET is created (like SF[(FF[x][y])]) at once?

```
import numpy as np

FF = np.arange(40000)
np.random.shuffle(FF)
#  FF = FF.reshape((200, 200))  # Only to understand 200x200 = 40000
FF = FF.reshape((40000,))

SF = np.random.choice(2, size=40000).astype(bool)  # Create Array with random boolean
TARGET = np.zeros((40000,), dtype=bool)  # Create Target array

for index in range(40000):  # This for should be replaced with numpy to create TARGET
    pos_in_SF_array = FF[index]  # get position in Second array out of First array at position 0..39999
    value_true_false_at_pos = SF[pos_in_SF_array]  # get True or False at the desired position
    TARGET[index] = value_true_false_at_pos  # Write it at the position index from TARGET

print("Example for take pos in first array and address the value of second array:")
print("Then write the True false in the Target array")
print(FF[12345])
print(SF[FF[12345]])
TARGET[12345] = SF[FF[12345]]  # Assign the Value

TARGET = TARGET.reshape(200, 200)  # Reshape it in the same manner as FF
print(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found the simplest solution regarding this topic [How to get the values from a NumPy array using multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162026/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-using-multiple-indices)

```
TARGET2 = (np.take(SF, FF)).reshape(200,200)
print(np.array_equal(TARGET, TARGET2))    # True
```