# how to get rows of 2d numpy array by index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a 2-D array that looks like this:

```
my_array = np.array([[1,7]
                     [2,4]
                     [3,10] 
                     [4,3] 
                     [5,23]])
```

and I have an index array which looks like this:

```
index_array = np.array([0,2,3])
```

as an output I want to get a matrix containing only the rows from the index array
so the shape of the output matrix should be (3,2) and it should look like this:

```
[[1,7]
 [3,10]
 [4,3]]
```

The solution shouldn't use a for loop and should work with any 2-D matrix.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the values from a NumPy array using multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162026/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-using-multiple-indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [numpy array slicing notation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to select your rows :D

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[1,7],
                     [2,4],
                     [3,10], 
                     [4,3],
                     [5,23]])

print(my_array[[0,2,3]])
```

`my_array[index_array]` would work as well

Answer (score 0):

not sure if a list comprehension qualifies as a for loop, but you can have this one-line solution:

```py
[list(my_array[i]) for i in index_array]
```

that will return `[[1, 7], [3, 10], [4, 3]]`.