# How use more indexed in an array 2D?

Tags: python, arrays

I´m trying to simplify my script using more indices for array; however, always get an IndexError.
This is part of my script:

```
# Set the values in x-axis, only for the first plot
axs[0].set_xlim(0, 1200)
axs[0].set_ylim(-800, 200)
# Set the range of values in x-axis
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
# Set the values in y-axis, only for the rest
axs[1].set_xlim(0, 1200)
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 9)
axs[2].set_xlim(0, 1200)
axs[2].set_ylim(0, 9)
```

Well, I think that these lines could be more simplified. For example, using:

```
axs[1,2].set_ylim(0, 9)
```

Where the y-axis has the range 0-9; however, when I tried to made that I have the error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

I understand the error partially; however, my question for this post is:

Is there a way to fix that problem to use in one line the ...[1,2]set_ylim...?
Or there is no way to do that?

Comment: What is `type(axs)`?

Comment: Thank you for the anwer. It´s a `numpy.ndarray` Any idea of what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the values from a NumPy array using multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162026/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-using-multiple-indices) You're still going to have to [`map()` the `set_ylim()` function to all results in the sliced array though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: I going to look at that post, I´m a beginner using matplotlip. I´m using the `numpy.ndarray` with this line: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=False, figsize=(15, 8))` It´s possible to use multiple indices with that? Sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look toward this:

```
def set_ylims(indices: list, vals: tuple):
    for i in indices: # For each passed index
        axs[i].set_ylim(*vals)  # Unpack vals and call set_ylim()
```

For example:

```
my_indices = [2,5,8]
set_ylims(my_indices, (0,9))
```

*Just in case, if you're intimidated my the `indices: list` part. It's a **type hint**, in here, it is just to provide clarity. For more, check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).*

Comment: I suppuse that with `axs[i].set_ylim(*vals)` in *vals I must set the values 0.9, am I correct?

Comment: @Mauri1313 yes. We may set the `set_ylims` to have two separate paramaters: `set_ylims(indices, a, b)` and then use them like here: `axs[i].set_ylim(a, b)`. You can choosse whatever is most appropriate in your program.

Comment: Great, thank you. I´m a beginner using matplotlip and python, anyway. Have a nice day!