# Optimizing .append nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Is there a more elegant (and fast) way to do something like this :

```
Seg = []

for i in components :
    Segg = []
    
    for j in i :

        Segg.append(np.array(points)[j]) 
    Seg.append(Segg)
```

I'm not very familiar with nested loops, even less when we must .append something twice.

EDIT : points is a 3-d array and components provided from networkx as a generator of sets of nodes, one for each component of a graph G.

Comment: What is your final goal...with numpy loops are usually the wrong approach.

Comment: I would say learn, first, with other methods to do it, and then make this snip faster.

Comment: The more Pythonic way is to use list comprehensions.

Comment: Even with .append ?

Comment: Could you provide the details on "components" and "points"?

Comment: Casting `points` to a numpy array every sub-iteration seems like a performance killer to me. After casting it once, I would look at `Seg = [[np_points[j] for j in i] for i in components]` Depending on how `j` relates to `points` the entire sub loop might be redundant though. We need to know a little more about your data i think.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer about speed without having an [mcve] to test on whether it actually speeds up things for your use case. And in the same vein ... is it even slow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the values from a NumPy array using multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162026/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-using-multiple-indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way that yields the same results is:

```
parray = np.array(points)
Seg = [[parray[j] for j in i] for i in components]
```

Comprehensions are the fastest and most efficient way of creating lists. Appending in loops isn't efficient.

Comment: This is way more faster, thanks a lot !